# Jquery input number with comma

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a strange behavior in jquery.

I'd like to get the value of a input field (type number). It's easier to show it with an example.

The function throws back an empty string when the value contains a comma.

```
$("#input[type='number']").on('change',function() {
            alert($(this).val());
        });
```

Why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Because for example, `1,2`, is not a number.

Comment: I've tried your code and it works, I've only removed the _#_. Could you share your html?

Comment: @Ben I know number 1,2 isn't a number but I need to treat this to replace comma with point. Or do you know any other method to do that?

Comment: @Manuel Then maybe using `type="number"` isn't the solution. Try using a normal textbox, and formatting/rejecting as they type (or on the `change` event)

Comment: I am working also with cakephp and your solution requires to change the helpers. So I prefer to use type="number" because it's ready to use

Comment: `1,2` would be considered a number in locales where the comma represents a decimal "point"

Comment: Using a comma for the thousands separator should not invalidate the number.  This is a fail on the part of jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML5's [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html) doesn't allow commas:

```
value = floating-point number
   A string representing a number
```

[floating-point numbe](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/datatypes.html#common.data.float)r:

```
A floating-point number consists of the following parts, in exactly the following order:

    1. Optionally, the first character may be a "-" character.
    2. One or more characters in the range "0—9".
    3. Optionally, the following parts, in exactly the following order:
        1. a "." character
        2. one or more characters in the range "0—9"
    Optionally, the following parts, in exactly the following order:
        1. a "e" character or "E" character
        2. optionally, a "-" character or "+" character
        3. One or more characters in the range "0—9".
```

Comment: Does this take into account localisation? Some countries use a comma as the decimal separator.

Comment: As written, there's nothing in the spec to allow for it. A browser MIGHT choose to translate a local format into HTML5-allowable format, but that's undefined behavior.

Comment: Well, my problem is to replace comma with point because I need to add my data into an sql database, is there any way?

Comment: prompt for type=text instead and validate the number separately.

Comment: I am working also with cakephp and your solution requires to change the helpers. So I prefer to use type="number" because it's ready to use

Comment: @Manuel It may be "ready to use", but it clearly doesn't work for your needs, so you need to do something else

Comment: exactly what ian said. "I have a banana, but need to use a hammer. how can I turn the banana into a hammer? I don't want to change the banana"

Answer (score -1):

Add this to the input: step="0.01"

so something like:

```
<input type="number"  step="0.01" />
```

Then 0.10 will be valid, I am not sure if comma will be treated as valid if your operating system use decimals as comma separated.